# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS goes into black screen with text for unexpected event everytime after sleep

Tags: boot, crash, bug-reporting

The photo is shown down below in the link (since I'm new to this subforum I can't post the picture directly). I had this a few days ago before I updated to Ubuntu 20 from 18. I thought the update would've helped but it's still the same problem. Every time I close my laptop to let it sleep then come back to flip up the screen this appears.

I am able to, sometimes, I believe click on the Windows command button then it brings me to the same black screen with plain text for me to login. However, it wants me to fill in a username as well which I am not sure what mine is for this OS. Whether I am able to get to this second stage of this weird login or not, I end up having to force shutdown and restart to launch Ubuntu properly. Anyone having similar experiences that can help?

[Post-sleep screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6YQ7.jpg)

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  so do you mean Ubuntu Core 20 and you've added a desktop? Ubuntu has used *year* format releases to mean *snap* only products since 2016. If you have an issue on one release (eg. Ubuntu Core 18), upgrading will seldom *fix* issues so they should be fixed before the upgrade, or you *upgrade via re-install*.  With Ubuntu Core 18, an upgrade to Ubuntu Core 20 changes no applications; as only the underneath OS base changes; all *snapped* applications are untouched - a benefit of the *snap* only *year* releases (& very different to *year.month* releases)

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I'm sort of a newbie and am not even sure what Ubuntu Core is since I've only heard it a few times. D:

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is a different product to Ubuntu Core 20; so please correct your question. You cannot upgrade a Ubuntu Core 18 system to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as they are different products.. so please correct, if it was a Ubuntu Core 18 system you need to clean install to switch to the 20.04 product.

Comment: I was using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS prior to upgrading. I did not even know Ubuntu Core existed. I simply followed the recommended upgrade popup everytime I launched Ubuntu.

Comment: Please correct your question; Ubuntu has had *year* or *snap* only products since 2016 so your question which uses 18 & 20 (*snap* only products) implies a different problem to what you intend.  You'll get better responses if your details are accurate & clear and don't require people to ask via comment & then read comments to understand - readers will just move on... If you complete what I've requested, I can delete my comments too.  FYI:  Bug reporting is off-topic on this Q&A site, it belongs on bug trackers (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)